# Suggested Layout Design for Simple Scheduler App for Blackberry

Tags: list, blackberry, scheduler

I am currently planning to develop a Blackberry application that mainly have 3 core functions inside. One of it will be a scheduler.

My question is, what will be the most efficient layout for a scheduler that can displays all the recorded schedules neatly like when we are editing and saving memo?

I am currently learning the use of Persistent Storage for this functions, so how to relate the functions to the end-user display?

Thanks,

Comment: I assume you mean calendar/time scheduler not OS scheduler right?

Comment: Yes, it is a Calendar/Time scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

```
ListField is the best option for your requirement to display all schedule . When user click on particular `row` of `ListField` it will redirect on `DetailScreen` . In Detail screen user can edit that schedule and Save in `Persistent Storage` .
```

Check below link for **Persistent Storage**.

1. [Download pdf from here](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/7693/Retrieve_a_collection_from_presistent_storage_510237_11.jsp)
2. [download demo example from here](http://blackberrytutor.info/tutorials/37-general/49-persistent-storage)

Comment: Other question, I am trying to create a new class which is a PersistentObject class. But when I try to Run it failed my with the message telling that Screen class can't implements Persistable. So how do I fix this one?

Comment: @ocinisme download psf from here . it will help you to integrate Persistent Object for Blackberry http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/1107/fundamentals.pdf